# What's @classmethod do outside of a class in Python?

Tags: python, annotations, metaprogramming, class-method, namedtuple

In the below code, if the `@classmethod` annotation is present, the inner def `new()` is allowed to stand in for the target's `__new__()` -- but the class is passed twice. If `@classmethod` is removed then we get an error like "". What is `@classmethod` doing here and is there a way to do without it? (My motivation is clarity: code I don't understand seems like an accident waiting to happen.)

```
"""Namedtuple annotation.

Creates a namedtuple out of a class, based on the signature of that class's
__init__ function. Defaults are respected. After namedtuple's initializer is
run, the original __init__ is run as well, allowing one to assign synthetic
parameters and internal book-keeping variables.

The class must not have varargs or keyword args.
"""     
import collections
import inspect


def namedtuple(cls):
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(cls.__init__)
    assert argspec.varargs is None
    assert argspec.keywords is None 
    non_self_args = argspec.args[1:]

    # Now we can create the new class definition, based on a namedtuple.
    bases = (collections.namedtuple(cls.__name__, non_self_args), cls)
    namespace = {'__doc__': cls.__doc__}
    newcls = type(cls.__name__, bases, namespace)

    # Here we set up the new class's __new__, which hands off to namedtuple's
    # after setting defaults.
    @classmethod
    def new(*args, **kwargs):
        kls, _kls_again = args[:2]              # The class is passed twice...?
        # Resolve default assignments with this utility from inspect.
        values = inspect.getcallargs(cls.__init__, None, *args[2:], **kwargs)
        values = [values[_] for _ in non_self_args]
        obj = super(newcls, kls).__new__(kls, *values)
        cls.__init__(obj, *values)              # Allow initialization to occur
        return obj
    # The @classmethod annotation is necessary because otherwise we get an
    # error like "unbound method new takes a class instance".

    newcls.__new__ = new

    return newcls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__new__` is treated as a *static* method, not a classmethod, and is looked up directly on the class when invoked by Python. Python passes in the class object as a first argument, explicitly. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument

By making it a classmethod, the method is bound to the class and the class is passed in automatically *in addition to the explicit class*, which is why you get it twice. A `classmethod` object is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) (as are `staticmethod`, `function` and `property` objects) and it is the lookup on a class or instance that triggers the binding behaviour.

You should not use `classmethod`. Python makes it a static method when creating the class, so if you were to use

```
def new(*args, **kwargs):
    # ...
namespace = {'__doc__': cls.__doc__, '__new__': new}
newcls = type(cls.__name__, bases, namespace)
```

rather than set it on the class after the fact, then omitting the `@classmethod` decorator is enough:

```
def new(*args, **kwargs):
    kls = args[0]
    # Resolve default assignments with this utility from inspect.
    values = inspect.getcallargs(cls.__init__, None, *args[1:], **kwargs)
    values = [values[_] for _ in non_self_args]
    obj = super(newcls, kls).__new__(kls, *values)
    cls.__init__(obj, *values)              # Allow initialization to occur
    return obj
```

Alternatively, make it a `staticmethod` manually:

```
@staticmethod
def new(*args, **kwargs):
    # ...

newcls.__new__ = new
```

Take into account that a `namedtuple`-produced class is *immutable*, so if the shadowed class `__init__` method tries to set arguments by the same names as the `__init__` arguments, you'll get an `AttributeError` exception.

Comment: @solidsnack Oops? (Thanks)

Comment: I'll try the static method route. As far as I can determine, the method must be added after the class is created, because we need access to the class definition (`newcls`) in the body of `new()` for the `super()` call.

Comment: @solidsnack the `newcls` closure is available when the method is called either way.